# Complex Callback Tests

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await

In a test function for a referenced `static` method `TriggerCallbacks`, which starts a sequence that is supposed to asynchronously invoke  `Callback` for a specified number of times, I need to do the following:

1. Count the number of times `Callback` is invoked
2. Validate the objects in `Callback`
3. Return from the test function after `Callback` was invoked for the expexted number of times,
   or after a specified timeout

The basic test function looks like this:

```
class TestProgram
{
    static void TestCallbacks()
    {   
        var numberOfCallbacks = 10;
        SomeClassFromReferencedDll.TriggerCallbacks(numberOfCallbacks,Callback);
        //1. Count the number of times Callback is invoked
        //2. Validate callbackObject for each time Callback is invoked
        //3. return after Callback was invoked 10 times, or timeout
    }
    private static void Callback(SomeClassFromReferencedDll.CallbackData callbackObject )
    {
        //Validate callbackObject
    }
}
```

How can I implement points 1 to 3 within this test function?

Comment: The naming convention for .NET is that `On*` methods are used to raise events, and not to subscribe to events.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
void TestCallbacks()
{   
    var numberOfCallbacks = 10;

    var actualCallbacks = 0; 
    
    SomeClassFromReferencedDll.TriggerCallbacks(numberOfCallbacks,Callback);
    //1. Count the number of times Callback is invoked
    //2. Validate callbackObject for each time Callback is invoked
    //3. return after Callback was invoked 10 times, or timeout


    Assert.AreEqual(expected: numberOfCallbacks, actual: actualCallbacks);

    static void Callback(SomeClassFromReferencedDll.CallbackData callbackObject )
    {
        //Validate callbackObject
        actualCallbacks++;
        if (actualCallbacks > numberOfCallbacks)
        {
            Assert.Fail($"Too many callbacks: {actualCallbacks}")
    } 
}
```